# How can I make my solidity skill too strong?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am solidity developer and have been coding in solidity for 6 months. I have made 6-7 projects with solidity. I want to make my solidity skill very strong. Give me some tips how can I do it?